# Choosing active SES ReceiptRuleSet in CloudFormation / Troposphere

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ses, troposphere

I am creating a ReceipRuleSet with troposphere like this :

```
ReceiptRuleSet(
    title="SesRuleset",
    RuleSetName="ses-ruleset"
)
```

However, when I upload the stack with the generated CloudFormation template, the RuleSet appears as inactive in SES.
Does anyone knows if there is a way to set the created RuleSet as active without having to interact with the online console nor the CLI ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be supported by Cloudformation. I found the following blog post leveraging a lambda doing an API call to activate the RuleSet after creation: https://binx.io/blog/2019/11/25/how-to-set-the-active-receipt-rule-set-in-ses-using-cloudformation/

This seemed one moving piece too many for me, so I'm currently activating the RuleSet through the console.

Answer (score 0):

troposphere maintaner here. I don't actually know a ton about SES, but have you included the ReceiptRuleSet in a ReceiptRule?  My guess is that if a RuleSet is not used by a Rule, it's probably inactive, since I can't see anything in either cloudformation or the API that would indicate you can set it to "active".

Comment: There is an API call for this : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SetActiveReceiptRuleSet.html
Technically, a ReceiptRuleSet can contain multiple ReceiptRule, an active RuleSet can contain no rule, and a RuleSet can contain Rules without being active. Since I can create one RuleSet for all my project, I ended up activating it with the AWS console once and for all. Thanks